# Can not Create Payment method on Stripe using LWC Salesforce

Tags: stripe-payments, salesforce, apex, lwc

**Error i get is - sending credit card numbers directly to the stripe api is generally unsafe.**

I need to insert a card to a user and return payment method id.

In stripe there is a option to fix this in settings but it will works only for testing.

Below methos is i am using to insert card to stripe for a stripe customer.

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static Map<String, TS_Stripe.StripeResponse> createCardOnStripe(TS_Stripe input) {
        Map<String, TS_Stripe.StripeResponse> responseMap = new Map<String, TS_Stripe.StripeResponse>();
        TS_Stripe.StripeResponse stripeResponse = new TS_Stripe.StripeResponse();
        System.debug('createCardOnStripe :: ' + input);

        try {
            String endpoint = BASE_URL + '/customers/' + input.stripeCardInput?.customerId + '/sources';

            String body = (!String.isBlank(input.stripeCardInput?.cardNumber))
                ? 'card[number]=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(input.stripeCardInput.cardNumber, 'UTF-8')
                : '';

            body += (!String.isBlank(input.stripeCardInput?.expMonth))
                ? '&card[exp_month]=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(input.stripeCardInput.expMonth, 'UTF-8')
                : '';

            body += (!String.isBlank(input.stripeCardInput?.expYear))
                ? '&card[exp_year]=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(input.stripeCardInput.expYear, 'UTF-8')
                : '';

            body += (!String.isBlank(input.stripeCardInput?.cvc))
                ? '&card[cvc]=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(input.stripeCardInput.cvc, 'UTF-8')
                : '';

            body += (!String.isBlank(input.stripeCardInput?.cardHolder))
                ? '&card[name]=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(input.stripeCardInput.cardHolder, 'UTF-8')
                : '';

            String response = makeStripeRequest('POST', endpoint, body);

            Map<String, Object> jsonResponse = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response);
            System.debug('JSON Response :: ' + jsonResponse);
            System.debug('jsonResponse :: ' + (String) jsonResponse.get('id'));
            String cardId = (String) jsonResponse.get('id');

            stripeResponse.response = jsonResponse;
            stripeResponse.cardId = cardId;
            responseMap.put('success', stripeResponse);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug(e);
            stripeResponse.errorMessage = e.getMessage();
            responseMap.put('error', stripeResponse);
        }

        return responseMap;
    }
```

below code is for make stripe request. I have added if needed.

```
public static String makeStripeRequest(String method, String endpoint, String body) {
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        request.setMethod(method);
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + ACCESS_TOKEN);
        request.setBody(body);

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

        return response.getBody();
    }
```

Comment: You should be using instead https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse

Comment: btw, it's better to use Stripe SDKs rather than having to write your own logic